# how to get current month Weekends list of calender control in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to get the list of dates of weekend of current month.
is there is any way i can store all weekend dates in my list

```
list<datetime> mylist=new list<datetime>();
```

i want to store the weekend dates in mylist of current month and same with next months
i m using asp.net calender control and i want to save the date of weekend in my list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For current month, you can do

```
var startDate = DateTime.Now;
var first = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, 1);
List<DateTime> weekends = new List<DateTime>();
for (int i = 0; i <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(startDate.Year, startDate.Month); i++)
{
    var nextDay = first.AddDays(i);
    if (nextDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || nextDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        weekends.Add(nextDay);
    }
}
```

You can do something very similar for next month.

Comment: thanks for ur reply but i need to get the weekend from asp.net calender control

Comment: @Wasif are you trying to select weekends on the calendar control?

Comment: What does "from the asp.net calendar control" mean?  If you just mean for the month/year shown in the control, you should be able to figure it out from Bala's answer.  "Hint:" use the property from the calendar instead of "Now".

Comment: @Bala  i want to store the weekends of selected month  i my list and then i check the date in database...

Comment: @Bala i understand ur logic now i m going to implement it on asp.net calender control thanks a Lot for ur reply :-)

Comment: @Wasif I changed the snippet slightly. you can try `var startDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;`

Comment: @Wasif - be sure to mark Bala's answer as, well, the answer if it helped you to figure out your issue.

Comment: Thanks bala i m asp.net Internee and developing a HRMS stand alone as a initial project Thanks a lot for ur help

Comment: @Bala R can you help me? i have week number of current month. i want that if week number not in current month then it will show week number month that is given. Actually i m able to show week but i m not able to update the date in calender

Comment: @Bala R i want to know that how to show a calendar of given date(date time picker

Answer (score 0):

repeat this for every week of month

```
 DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime saturday;
        DateTime sunday;
        if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
        {
            saturday = date.AddDays(5);
            sunday = date.AddDays(6);
        }else if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
        {
            saturday = date.AddDays(4);
            sunday = date.AddDays(5);
        }
        else if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        {
            saturday = date.AddDays(3);
            sunday = date.AddDays(4);
        }
        else if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
        {
            saturday = date.AddDays(2);
            sunday = date.AddDays(3);
        }
        else if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
        {
            saturday = date.AddDays(1);
            sunday = date.AddDays(2);
        }
        else if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            saturday = date.AddDays(0);
            sunday = date.AddDays(1);
        }
        else if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            saturday = date.AddDays(-1);
            sunday = date.AddDays(0);
        }
```

note:

next week:

```
date.AddDays(7);
```

previous week:

```
date.AddDays(-7);
```

Comment: but i want to get the weekend from the asp.net calender control of selected month and then i want to save them in list

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get weekend days of visible moth
public List<DateTime> getWeekEndDays(DateTime dt)
{
    List<DateTime> result = new List<DateTime>();

    int month = dt.Month;
    dt = dt.AddDays(-dt.Day + 1);//Sets dt to first day of month

    //Sets dt to the first week-end day of the month;
    if (dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        while (dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            dt = dt.AddDays(1);

    //Adds the week-end day and stops when next month is reached.
    while (dt.Month == month)
    {
        result.Add(dt);
        dt = dt.AddDays(dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ? 1 : 6);
    }
    return result;
}
```